# Верно ли употребление единственного числа?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

«В разгаре не только курортный, но и археологический сезон». Верно ли единственное число, «сезон»?

Answer (score 2):

***В разгаре не только курортный, но и археологический сезон.***

Имя существительное, которому предшествует два или несколько определений, указывающих на разновидности предметов, ставится **в форме единственного числа:**

3. если между определениями стоят противительные, разделительные или **сопоставительные союзы,** например: не норвежский, а голландский конькобежец; латинский или готический шрифт; то широкая, то узкая дорога; как в прошлом, так и в нынешнем году; если не в соседнем, то в более отдаленном регионе;

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm